# No visible interface for UITabBarItem when trying to set selectedImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I've seen that you can add a selectedImage as well as an image for a UITabBarItem, so I amended a Cordova plugin to add that:

```
UIImage *tabIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImage *selectedTabIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedImage];
tabIcon = [tabIcon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
selectedTabIcon = [selectedTabIcon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:tabIcon tag:tag selectedImage:selectedTabIcon];
```

with the selectedImage variable being a string passed in by the plugin here:

```
  NSString  *name      = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString  *title     = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
  NSString  *imageName = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
  NSString *selectedImage = [arguments objectAtIndex:3];
  int tag              = [[arguments objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
```

However when I try to compile this I get the following error:

> /Users/tomchambers/work/cordova-ios-tab-bar/src/ios/CDVTabBar.m:266:34:
>   error: no visible @interface
>             for 'UITabBarItem' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:image:tag:selectedImage:'
>           item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:tabIcon tag:tag selectedImage:sel...
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>
> ```
> ** BUILD FAILED **
> ```

I am not experienced with objective C, so I think it might be something simple I'm missing here.

---

When using different method (images definitely exist):

```
  UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"random" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"www/assets/images/tab-bar-icons/ic_mail_outline.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"www/assets/images/tab-bar-icons/ic_mail_outline.png"]];
```

---

```
2016-02-08 11:48:31.367 Movidiam[1847:843403] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.9.2 is starting.
2016-02-08 11:48:31.369 Movidiam[1847:843403] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2016-02-08 11:48:31.372 Movidiam[1847:843403] Unlimited access to network resources
2016-02-08 11:48:31.679 Movidiam[1847:843403] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 152.289033ms
2016-02-08 11:48:31.680 Movidiam[1847:843403] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 152.797997ms
2016-02-08 11:48:31.847 Movidiam[1847:843403] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2016-02-08 11:48:34.294 Movidiam[1847:843403] -[__NSDictionaryM intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f82d430
2016-02-08 11:48:34.295 Movidiam[1847:843403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f82d430'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1834f9900 0x182b67f80 0x18350061c 0x1834fd5b8 0x18340168c 0x1000eaf4c 0x100102528 0x100101df4 0x183ebbe20 0x1834b0efc 0x1834b0990 0x1834ae690 0x1833dd680 0x1848ec088 0x188254d90 0x1000c7814 0x182f7e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you have used to instantiate TabBarItem doesn't exist. You must use any one of them:

```
UITabBarItem * item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] tag:1];
```

OR

```
UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"]];
```

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between the second option and what I am using currently. They both seem to use `UITabBarItem alloc`

Comment: You can either use tag or selected image but you are using both things which doesn't exist on UITabBarItem.

Comment: @Tom Did you understand what actually the problem is?

Comment: I understand now - I see they have different signatures. I am a javascript developer so I am not used to function overloading!

Comment: @Tom There is no method/function overloading in Objective-C. The methods don’t only have different signatures, their names are different as well, one is called `initWithTitle:image:tag:`, the other method is named `initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:`.

Comment: @ShehzadAli using that method instead without the tag, it compiles ok with Cordova, but when I run on device I get the selector not on instance error shown in the question.

Comment: Remove previous build from your device. Clean project and try again.

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Tom are you getting compile time error on device and you aren't getting that error on simulator? Please reverify your code if its compile time error. You are doing something wrong while writing the code.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong, had to restart everything twice, but eventually it worked without errors. Thanks.